# How to change macro escape char in Apache Velocity

Tags: latex, velocity, template-engine, xelatex

I'm using apache velocity in front of LaTeX. The # and $ escape chars are conflicting with LaTeX. I want to replace # with %% and $ with @@ to avoid the conflicts. Simply using a string replace on the source file code is not a good solution because I have to use things like #parse and #include. The parsed/included file should also be able to use the modified escape chars. Is there a way to configure this? Is there a configuration option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom resource loader to modify files loaded by #parse:

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("resource.loader", "customloader");
props.put("customloader.resource.loader.class", CustomLoader.class.getName());
engine.init(props);

public static class CustomLoader extends FileResourceLoader {
    public InputStream getResourceStream(String arg0) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        InputStream original = super.getResourceStream(arg0);
        //TODO modify original, return modified
        original.close();
    }
}
```